# Junit test for a method which calls another void method of another component

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I have a method A (Check) on which it calls another void method B(wantToSkip). A will throw one exception for which I am going to write junit test. In this case want to avoid calling method B. How can I achieve that?
Code is as below:

```
class A {
    Class c = new Class();
    Public void setC(C c) {
    this.c = c;
}
    String check(){
        try{
            //do something
        } catch(Exception test) {
            c.wantToSkip();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Here I just want to make sure exception test is thrown but want to skip calling method inside it.
I tried following but did not work

```
@Test//(expected= Exception.class)
public void test(){
class c = Mockito.spy(new class());
Mockito.doNothing().when(c).wantToSkip();
check(some arguments);
}
```

Comment: Assuming method A is check(); where is your method B? Is it wantToSkip()?

Comment: Also, have you made an attempt to write your JUnit?

Comment: @Balkrishna edited the question for your enquiry. I tried which did not work. Also I am looking for best appraoch

Comment: You cannot avoid invocation of method wantToSkip() on exception because that is the behaviour of check(). What you can do is you can mock object c so that you don't do anything when this method is called.

Comment: If c is mocked, make sure there is a way to assign this mock dependency to class A through setter or constructor injection.

Comment: @ user2953113: Class A has setter to set C

Comment: @user123475: Have you used that setter to set c in your JUnit?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a setter for Class c, you can use Mockito to achieve what you want to do.

Your unit test would look something like this:

```
@Mock private Class mockC;

@Test
public void test(){
    A a = new A();
    a.setC(mockC);
    a.check(some arguments);
}
```

Alternatively you could take your `Class c` in the constructor, in which case your test could look like this.

```
@Mock private Class mockC;

@Test
public void test(){
    A a = new A(mockC);
    a.check(some arguments);
}
```

The mockC has no behaviour specified for when `c.wantToSkip()` is called, so it won't do anything.

The latest non-beta version for mockito is here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19